# How to Identify if the subgroup is abelian?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

How do you identify if the subgroups of the symmetry group of the square are abelian? I already identified all the subgroups but I kinda got stuck in identifying which of them are abelian. thanks!

Comment: Do you know the order of the smallest nonabelian group?

Comment: If worst comes to worst, you can always write out all their group tables. Alternatively, you could look at the group table of the full group, see which pairs of elements *don't* commute (there aren't too many), and then see whether any of those pairs appear together in a (proper) subgroup.

Answer (score 1):

let $H$ be one of the subgroups you have found, and pick two symmetries from $H$, say, $\phi, \phi'$. Now take two vertices $u,v$ of the square (not diagonally opposite). Check that $\phi\circ \phi'$ and $\phi'\circ \phi$ on both the vertices give the same result. This will show this subgroup $H$ is abelian.